# Applet doesn't want to open in browser

Tags: java, image, browser, graphics, icons

My applet doesn't want to open in browser. I think that all is because of graphics.

I load it like this:

```
icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
```

and use like this:

```
logo = new JLabel(icon);
```

Without graphics, everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Use class loader to find images that are bundled in the `jar` file.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

URL imageURL = classLoader.getResource("images/icon.logo");
JLabel logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageURL));
```

See also:

- [How do I enable and view the Java Console for Linux?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_console_linux.xml)
- [How do I enable and view the Java Console?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)

---

Update

```
 +Project
 |
 |   
 +-src
 |  |
 |  |   
 |  +path
 |  |
 |  |-TargetClass.java
 |  ...
 |
 +-resources
 |  |
 |  |
 |  +-images       
 |  |    |
 |  ...  |-icon.logo
 ...     ...
```

Comment: Huh..  Noise deleted.

Comment: Do I have to create folder "resources"?

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've got NullPointerException error.